# Integrating ActiveAdmin and adauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, active-directory, activeadmin

I have a running Rails application, using ActiveAdmin and its models to autenticate users. Now I'm interested in moving to an ActiveDirectory authentication, so my users can validate wiht the domain's users.
I've been trying adauth and it looks like a great gem, but I'm a little bit lost when trying to "mix" this gem with my ActiveAdmin authentication. I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one in doing it, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally was able to manage to integrate AD in ActiveAdmin.

Here's what I did, in case someone is interested:

- Include gem 'adauth' in your gems
- Execute bundle install
- Execute rails g adauth:config
- Configure the config/initializers/adauth.rb for your AD connection. For example, if your domain is example.com, you must include:

  ```
  c.domain = "example.com" 
  c.server = "IP address of your domain controller"
  c.base = "dc=example, dc=com"
  ```
- Execute rails g adauth:sessions
- Modify your application_controller.rb. Mine was:

  ```
  class ApplicationController< ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery
      helper_method :current_user
      def current_user
          @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
      end
      def authenticate_user!
         if current_user.nil?
             redirect_to '/sessions/new', :error => "Invalid Login" 
         end
      end
  end
  ```
- Execute rails g adauth:user_model user install_adauth.
  This creates the migration install_adauth, but for some reason it was empty. I had to fill it myself with:

  ```
  class InstallAdauth < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def up
          create_table :users do |u|
              u.string 'login'
              u.text 'group_strings'
              u.string 'name'
              u.string 'ou_strings'
          end
      end
      def down
          drop_table :users
      end
  end
  ```
- Execute rake db:migrate
- Modify your sessions_controller.rb. Mine was:

  ```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
          redirect_to '/admin' if current_user 
      end
      def create
          ldap_user = Adauth.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
          if ldap_user
              user = User.return_and_create_with_adauth(ldap_user)
              session[:user_id] = user.id
              redirect_to '/admin' 
          else
              redirect_to '/sessions/new', :error => "Invalid Login" 
          end
      end

      def destroy
          session[:user_id] = nil
          redirect_to '/sessions/new' 
      end
  end
  ```
- So far the validation through ActiveAdmin still works. To switch to ActiveDirectory we must change the file initializers/active_admin.rb

  ```
  # config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!

  #config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
  ```
- In my case, I needed to restart Apache too.

If anytime we want to switch back to ActiveAdmin, we just need to undo the last change

Comment: I know this is old, but it's still relevant. Is there anything that's updated since '12?